# Collect a field value into an array by ID field in an object array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, cycle, node.js-fs

I am unable to modify JSON file. Tried to use all my knowledge of loops (map,filter) and conditions(if,else) JavaScript. But nothing comes out. Please tell me how to make such a file from this file

```json
[{
    "model": "2002R \"Protection Pack - Mirage Grey",
    "img": "2002r-protection-pack-mirage-grey.jpg"
  },
  {
    "model": "2002R \"Protection Pack - Mirage Grey",
    "img": "2002r-protection-pack-mirage-grey-2.jpg"
  },
  {
    "model": "550 \"White Black",
    "img": "BB550HA1-2.jpg"
  },
  {
    "model": "550 \"White Black",
    "img": "BB550HA1-3.jpg"
  },]
```

Should be like this

```json
   [{
    "model": "2002R \"Protection Pack - Mirage Grey",
    "img": ["2002r-protection-pack-mirage-grey.jpg", "2002r-protection-pack-mirage-grey-2.jpg"]
  },
  {
    "model": "550 \"White Black",
    "img": ["BB550HA1-2.jpg","BB550HA1-3.jpg"]
  },
]
```

I tried this. But no correct result.

```js
let modelsArray = [];
let prevModel = '';
let currentModel = '';
let pictureArray = [];
let counterModel = 0;

fs.readFile(path, 'utf-8', (err, data) => {
  if (err) console.log(err.message);

  try {
    const dataArr = JSON.parse(data);

    const newArr = dataArr.map((item, ind) => {
      currentModel = item.model;

      pictureArray.push(item['img']);

      if (modelsArray.length == 0) {
        modelsArray[counterModel] = { model: item.model };
        prevModel = currentModel;
      }

      if (prevModel !== item.model) {
        counterModel++;
        modelsArray[counterModel] = { model: item.model };
      }

      prevModel = currentModel;


      
    });
```

Please give me advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Array::reduce` is a good option to collect data from an array. Here we have an accumulator of the result array and a map where we can easily find already added models to add images to them:

```
r.map.get(model)?.img.push(img)
```

if a model isn't found add it to both the array and the map:

```
r.map.set(model, r.arr[r.arr.length] = {model, img: [img]});
```

```js
const models = [{
    "model": "2002R \"Protection Pack - Mirage Grey",
    "img": "2002r-protection-pack-mirage-grey.jpg",
    "brand": "test brand"
  },
  {
    "model": "2002R \"Protection Pack - Mirage Grey",
    "img": "2002r-protection-pack-mirage-grey-2.jpg"
  },
  {
    "model": "550 \"White Black",
    "img": "BB550HA1-2.jpg"
  },
  {
    "model": "550 \"White Black",
    "img": "BB550HA1-3.jpg"
  },];
  
const images = models.reduce((r, {model, img, ...props}) => {
  r.map.get(model)?.img.push(img) ?? 
  r.map.set(model, r.arr[r.arr.length] = {model, img: [img], ...props});
  return r;
}, {arr: [], map: new Map}).arr;

console.log(images);
```

Comment: One more question please. What if i have not only 2 fields in models. 
  {
    "model": "2002R \"Protection Pack - Mirage Grey",
    "brand": "New Balance",
    "img": "2002r-protection-pack-mirage-grey.jpg"
  },{
    "model": "2002R \"Protection Pack - Mirage Grey",
    "brand": "New Balance",
    "img": "2002r-protection-pack-mirage-grey-2.jpg"
  }
How should i change map?

Comment: @SharpLon use `...props` to collect the rest of properties, updated the answer

Comment: @SharpLon it's the spread syntax, learn here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax

Comment: Thank you.  Should i use spread syntax, after when reduce method finished work ?

Comment: @SharpLon i dont understand your quesiton, but, yes, you could use the spread syntax in your JS code, it's a modern feature of JS

Comment: I meant should I use the spread operator after the reduce method is done? Or insert the values ​​into the array with three and more fields during the loop?

Comment: @SharpLon `...props` will handle any number of extra props, no need to modify the code

Comment: @SharpLon btw you have 15 reputation now and can upvote my answer (the arrow up). that way i'll be rewarded 10 points and will be motivated to help you in the future, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Since you expect the `model` property to be unique, I'd just use either a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) or Object-like-a-Map for this:

```
const data = /* original dataset here */;
const output = {};

for (const item of data) {
  output[item.model] = output[item.model] || [];
  output[item.model].push(item.img);
}
```

If you want to reformat that output back to an Array, you could use [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries):

```
[...Object.entries(output)].map([model, img] => { model, img });
```